# Unexpected Error ID - not sure why (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11

Im implementing a C++ program, for project reasons it must be turned in one file so I cannot put what you normally would into a separate header file, it is just at the top of my file. I'm getting this error

```
project1.cpp:194:12: error: expected unqualified-id
OrderOfOps(const std::string& in)
           ^
project1.cpp:194:12: error: expected ')'
project1.cpp:194:11: note: to match this '('
OrderOfOps(const std::string& in)
```

Here are the lines of code in question: 
Constructor part which would be a header:

```
class OrderOfOps {
public:
    // Constructor
    OrderOfOps(const std::string& in);

private:
    std::string m_inString;
};
```

Problem Area:

```
bool IsNumber(const std::string& num)
{
    std::string::const_iterator it = num.begin();

    // Look up locale method
    while (it != num.end() && std::isdigit(*it, std::locale())) {
        ++it;
    }

    return !num.empty() && it == num.end();
}

// Constructor
OrderOfOps(const std::string& in)
{
    m_inString = in;
}
```

Comment: Provide a [MCVE] that reproduces your error please.

Comment: Try `OrderOfOps::OrderOfOps(const std::string& in)`

Comment: @songyuanyao wow. im so dumb. I can't believe i didn't catch that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Although you can't separate the code into a header file and a source file, `#include "header.h"` just does a purely textual insertion, so the compiler proper would see the same thing anyway.  Your problem is that:

```
OrderOfOps(const std::string& in)
```

is not how to define a constructor outside the class definition.  You need:

```
OrderOfOps::OrderOfOps(const std::string& in)
```